# ZKTeco Push SDK

Tags: c#, .net, sdk, device, zkteco

i'm new to ZKteco devices! I am using a Zkteco device. I have a Zkteco Device and I have downloaded a standalone SDK, but this SDK doesn't trigger the events, (for example OnVerify, or OnAttTransaction).
So, I read in some articles, that I need to use Push SDk, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 12):

**I took one month to find that for that PUSH SDK and ADMS, clearly ZKTeco is not open to share that. so I had try to proceed otherwise. Here is the solution I had implement and it work properly.**

The push SDK is just HTTP request made by ZKTeco device to the Bioserver.
You can use a tool like [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/) to scan HTTP requests made by your device and implement same request/response on your own server.

For exemple, the ZKTeco device model MB560-VL send requests like this one

```
GET http://[SERVER-IP:PORT]/iclock/getrequest?SN=XXXXXXXXXX
```

and if like the BioTime software, your server just send

```
OK
```

as response in *text/plain*, your device will view your server as a "BioTime"

*Note that your ZkTeco Device should have ADMS support, so that you will first configure SERVER-IP and PORT on the device (see your official device documentation on [ZKTeco website](https://www.zkteco.com/))*

**User registration**

When a user is registered on the device, the device send this request

```
POST /iclock/cdata?SN=XXXXXXXXXX&table=OPERLOG&Stamp=9999
```

with user information on the HTTP buffer. something like this one

```
PIN=2\tName=Johny Deep\tPri=0\tPasswd=\tCard=\tGrp=1\tTZ=0000000100000000\tVerify=0\tViceCard=\tStartDatetime=0\tEndDatetime=0\n
```

your server should just parse this data and respond OK to this request

**User logs (clock_in / clock_out) Device request**

```
POST /iclock/cdata?SN=XXXXXXXXXX&table=ATTLOG&Stamp=9999
```

the data sent by device on HTTP data buffer looks like

```
2\t2022-07-12 16:00:20\t1\t15\t\t0\t0\t\t\t43\n
```

As you can see you parse this string with *'\t'* as the separator of informations

- the first integer is the *User-PIN*,
- the second part is the *date and time*,
- the third part is *clock-in if value==0* and *clock-out if value==1*

Here is an exemple of implementation with Python

```
@http.route('/iclock/getrequest', type='http', auth="public", csrf=False)
def zk_bio_device_ping(request):
    print("----------DEVICE PING-----------")
    print(request.GET)
    return HttpResponse("OK", content_type='text/plain')

@http.route('/iclock/getrequest', type='http', auth="public", csrf=False)
def zk_bio_device_push(request):
    print("----------DEVICE SEND DATA----------")
    print(request.GET) 
    print(request.body.decode('utf-8'))   
    return HttpResponse("OK", content_type='text/plain')
```

**Device do not use any authentification to communicate with server ! I'm pretty sure that's a big security issue.**

Comment: `security issues` are on brand for ZKTeco.

Comment: also works for iclock9000-G :) thank you so much brother ....

Comment: what about time update? when it connect to server, machine changes the time to GMT +8

Comment: works for UFACE302 and F22

Comment: This is nice! Do you manage know how I can respond to device so that it will send back user list currently registered?